# Ruby on Rails: What is the simplest way to write an binary file which is to be get remotely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the simplest way to write an binary file which is to be get remotely?

Data you have:

- The url to the image

What I currently have is:

```
url = URI.parse(photo['source'])
File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/export/albums/#{album_name}/#{photo_name}", 'w'){ |f| f.write(Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| http.get(url.path)}.body)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `open-uri`, which allows you to read from a URL as though it were a file.  Note the "b" is significant as a modifier to the open mode especially if you run in Windows.

```
require 'open-uri'
open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/export/albums/#{album_name}/#{photo_name}", 'wb') do |dest|
  open(URI.parse(photo['source']), 'rb') do |src|
    dest.write(src.read)
  end
end
```

Note this reads the entire file into memory before writing it out.  For large files, you may want to read and write in blocks.

Comment: It would be better to use `Rails.root` as `RAILS_ROOT` will produce a warning in newer versions of Rails. Also be sure that the path you're saving the file to exists or this will raise an exception.